# Check specific days exist in a set range of given weeks and add to list

Tags: c#, list, date, days

What would be the best choice in getting and returning a list of specific dates between a 3 week range?

My intent is to create delivery dates based on a delivery centre's given days they are available

`public List<DayOfWeek> DeliveryDays { get; set; }`

DeliveryDays contains set values from 0-6 (0 being Sunday, 1 Monday, etc.)

I want to get those values, pass them through 3 weeks worth of following dates, and return those delivery days in a list (so only those centre's can order on select days).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public List<DateTime> CalculateAvailableDeliveryDates()
        {

            //Loop through 3 weeks of days
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;                                                            //Specify today's date
            DateTime totalDateCount = today.AddDays(1);                                                 //Plus one day on each time counted

            var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 21).Select(days => totalDateCount.AddDays(days)).ToList();  //Count from 0 to 21 (3 weeks worth of days). On each count, run totalDateCount

            //if exists in deliveryDayList
                //add to dates via dates.Add func

            if (DeliveryDays.Contains(DayOfWeek.Monday))
            {
                //action
            } //and so on for each day

            //return specific dates from date range
            return dates;
        }
```

currently I get a readout of 21 days. The if statement does nothing and is only serving as an example of my logic.

Would the best method be: rather than getting a list first, to do a check and nest if/case statements based on the DeliveryDates per centre and then return them into a list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a list of `DayOfWeek`, you can select all dates in the next `21` days that match one of those days of the week using `System.Linq`. The `Enumerable.Range` selects a range of numbers, `Select` will then select a bunch of `DateTime` objects representing `Today` plus some number of days, and `Where` is used to filter the results, comparing the `DayOfWeek` for each date to see if it exists in `DeliveryDays`:

```
List<DayOfWeek> DeliveryDays = new List<DayOfWeek>();

public List<DateTime> GetAvailableDeliveryDates()
{
    // 1. Get a range of numbers representing the days to add
    //      to today, which will make up our range of dates
    // 2. Select a date using Today.AddDays for each number 
    // 3. Filter on only days which are contained in DeliveryDays

    return Enumerable.Range(0, 21)  // Define the range           
        .Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(i))  // Select the range
        .Where(date => DeliveryDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek))  // Filter the range
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! I'm still quite alien to the concepts of DateTime in ranges. Much appreciated.